# function for showing totals in footer throwing strange numbers. How to solve this?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an angular material table like this:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="mixDetails" matSort matSortActive="index" matSortDirection="asc">
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 4%">
                      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
                      </mat-checkbox>
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 4%;">
                      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
                      </mat-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="width: 4%; padding-left: 5px">
                      Total
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 4%">#</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i=index" style="width: 4%">{{i + 1}}</td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="width: 4%">
                      {{mixDetails.data.length}}
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="component">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Component</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" style="padding-left: 5px" *ngIf="!editMode">
                        {{row.synonym?.compound.compoundName}}
                        <mat-icon *ngIf="row.synonym?.compound.isToxic" style="color: orangered">warning</mat-icon>
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf="editMode">
                        <ng-select [items]="synonyms"
                                   appearance="outline"
                                   bindLabel="otherName"
                                   bindValue="synonymId"
                                   [clearable]="false"
                                   [(ngModel)]="row.synonymId"
                                   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ng-select>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="concentration">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 5%; max-width: 5%;">Conc</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 5%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px" *ngIf="!editMode">
                        {{row.molePercentage}}
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf="editMode" class="my-inline-form-field-wrapper" style="width: 80px; padding: 0 0.5em;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row.molePercentage" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="uom">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 4%">UOM</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 4%; text-align: left">
                      <div style="padding-left: 5px" *ngIf="!editMode">{{row.uom}}</div>
                      <div *ngIf="editMode" style="width: 80px; padding: 0 0.5em" class="my-inline-form-field-wrapper">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                          <mat-select [(value)]="row.uom">
                            <mat-option value="ppm">ppm</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="ppb">ppb</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="ppt">ppt</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="%">%</mat-option>
                          </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="balance">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 4%">Bal</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 4%">
                      <mat-checkbox [checked]="row.balance" (change)="balanceChecked(row)"></mat-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="molePercentage">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 8%">Mole %</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 8%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px">
                        {{row.molePercentage}}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="grams">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 8%">Grams</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 8%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px">
                        {{row.grams}}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="product">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 8%">Product</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 8%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px" *ngIf="!editMode">
                        {{row.productCharge | currency}}
                      </div>
                      <div style="width: 85px; padding: 0 0.5em;" *ngIf="editMode"  class="my-inline-form-field-wrapper">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row.productCharge" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="width: 8%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px">
                        {{getProductTotal() | currency}}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="analytic">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 6%">Analytic</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 6%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px">
                        {{row.analyticCharge | currency}}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="width: 6%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px">
                        {{getAnalyticalChargeTotal() | currency}}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="mixing">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 6%">Mixing</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 6%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px">
                        {{row.mixingCharge | currency}}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef style="width: 6%; text-align: right">
                      <div style="padding-right: 5px">
                        {{getMixingChargeTotal() | currency}}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="ghs">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 4%">GHS</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 4%">
                      <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
                      [style.background]="row.impurityAdjustedGrams < 0 ? 'coral' : ''"></tr>
                  <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns;"></tr>
                </table>
```

and have the **getProductTotal** function in my typescript as:

```
getProductTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.mixDetails.data.length; i++) {
    total = total + this.mixDetails.data[i].productCharge;
  }

  return total;
}
```

when it loads the data everything is ok and normal all numbers and totals show values that are ok, but when I got in to edit mode and type something in a row in the product charge column then the total goes off the hook showing values way bigger than it should. Let's say for example it had this values 60,20,25,50 then the total should be 155, when it loads for the first time it is ok; whenever 
I edit let's change 20 with 45 then the total should be 175 but I got values like 60,452550. I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong here; if I'm then can someone show the direction please and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

for anybody else that runs into this the problem was the function was overriding the type of the total and converting it to a string so instead of adding numbers it was adding strings (concatenating them). what I did to solve everything was to add a plus sign to convert string to number in the function:

total = total + (+this.mixDetails.data[i].productCharge);